# Android tablayout text alignment changed on change from 22.2.1 to 23.1.0

Tags: text-alignment, android-tablayout

I had just updated the android design support library and i find the text alignment is changed.

please find the screenshot under.

[image]

as you can see the "MORE" is not aligned properly.

here is the code snippet

```
TextView tabFour = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabFour.setText("More");
    tabFour.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_menu, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setCustomView(tabFour);
```

and here is the xml body of tablayout and its custom layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_heightPercent="10%"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/croutonview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and here is the custom tab layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/tab"
android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
android:textSize="@dimen/tab_label"
android:fontFamily="@string/font_fontFamily_medium"/>
```